How do I calculate the significance level (in Gaussian Sigma) of a particle classification's classier results/
I'm doing a high school project for which I'm training a Neural Network to classify signal and background events with this dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/janus137/supersymmetry-dataset/data and the output I receive is a number between 0 and 1 where 0 means the classifier is certain it's background and 1 means the classifier is certain it is signal. My question is that after training and testing it, say I use it to predict 10,000 events that are background and signal, how do I get the significance level? I get that this is not some actual discovery but feel like it would be good for the project but I can't figure out how this works. I get the idea of hypothesis testing, nuisance variables and was understanding likelihood ratio until I read that you can never know the prior distributions so can't really calculate likelihood ratio. I know that this paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.4735) was able to do it but doesn't really explain how. And as a follow up-question, how do you decide the proportion of background-to-signal events to be used in your "discovery", isn't that influencing the significance level? This paper uses 100 signal with 1000 +- 50 background but doesn't really explain how they got that.
